# How can i merge and concatenate columns in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of proteins with their localization that looks like this:

```
Protein_loc <- data.frame(
Pro_ID = c("Palid", "Tars", "Palid", "Eef2", "Actn1", "Tars"),
Loc = c("Actin cyto", "Actin cyto", "Axon", "Aggresome", "Cell junc", "Cell junc"))
```

And, I would like to merge and concatenate it into a data frame that looks like this:

```
Subcell_loc <- data.frame(
Loc = c("Actin cyto", "Axon", "Aggresome", "Cell junc"),
Pro_ID = c("Palid, Tars", "Palid", "Eef2", "Actn1, Tars"))
```

I can do this in Excel rather easily with the concatenate function, but I can't find a way to do this in R.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I tried paste, merge, melt and cast and R pivot tables.  Getting counts per location is no problem.  But getting proteins per location in one cell has been difficult.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to using R. It looks like you just don't know which function you should use. We can use `aggregate`:

```
Subcell_loc <- aggregate(Pro_ID ~ Loc, Protein_loc, paste, sep = ", ")
```

Output is

```
         Loc      Pro_ID
1 Actin cyto Palid, Tars
2  Aggresome        Eef2
3       Axon       Palid
4  Cell junc Actn1, Tars
```

This will apply function `paste(, sep = ", ")` to all `Pro_ID` by group `Loc`. You can learn more on `aggregate` from `?aggregate`. The `Pro_ID ~ Loc` is a formula, where the left hand side depends on the right hand side. You can learn more from `?formula`. It is particularly useful for building statistical models.

The function `paste()` is used for concatenating strings. Try:

```
paste("abc", "def", sep = ", ")
```

It concatenates string "abc" with "def", with a separator ", " in the middle. You can also try `sep = " * "`.

Comment: WOW, that works perfectly.  Thanks so much for your help